# Html Agility Pack - Replace HTML between two comments

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm using Html Agility Pack for build a library with different functionalities.

One of them is:

- search into HTML all the HTML parts contained between "start comment tag"  and "end comment tag"
- replace all HTML for the HTML part that matches one search string

For example:

- I need to search HTML parts contained between `<!-- data-example-start`   start tag and  `<!-- data-example-end` end tag. Both are keyword (comments starts with those keywords)
- The HTML part to replace is the one that contains the keyword "hello"

```html
<body>
    <p>Title 
    </p>
    <!-- data-example-start-try_1 -->
    <div> 
    </div>
    <span id="hello"> Hi
    </span>
    <!-- data-example-end-try_1 -->
    <!-- data-example-start-goodbye 2-->
    <div> 
    <span id="bye"> Bye
    </span>
    </div>
    <p>
    </p>
    <!-- data-example-end-goodbye 2-->
</body>
```

In this case I expect to replace the first HTML part contained between `<!-- data-example-start-try_1 -->` and `<!-- data-example-end-try_1 -->`, because inside there is the Search Word "hello" that I'm searching for.

How can I select, into Html Agility Pack , HTML parts contained between two HTML comments?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is an online example that shows how to get nodes between comment:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/JlkMot

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var docNode = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;

var descendants = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().ToList();

var startNode = descendants.FindIndex(x => x.InnerHtml == "<!-- data-example-start-try_1 -->");
var endEnd = descendants.FindIndex(x => x.InnerHtml == "<!-- data-example-end-try_1 -->");

if (startNode != -1 && endEnd != 1)
{
    var betweenNodes = descendants.GetRange(startNode + 1, endEnd - startNode - 1);

    foreach (var node in betweenNodes)
    {
        // show 2 times "Hi", once for the span, once for the text
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
    }
}
```